# Find which files in a folder are not known to the apt package manager

Tags: debian, apt

I have found a file (say "badfile") in `/usr/bin` which do not seem to belong to any package installed on my system:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/badfile
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/badfile
$ apt-file search /usr/bin/badfile
# nothing is returned
```

I think I want to remove this file or move it to `/usr/local/bin`. This being said, presumably, there could be other such files. Is there a way to list all files in a certain repository (here, `/usr/bin/`) that the Debian `apt` package manager does not know about?

Comment: Just a note of caution if you are considering extending this to configuration files: you may come across files (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` comes to mind) that aren't part of any dpkg filelist, but instead are created on-the-fly by a package's pre/post installation script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass multiple filenames to `dpkg -S` to report on all the files in one go

eg

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/* > /dev/null
```

Now this isn't perfect; symbolic links don't get reported properly

eg

```
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/lzdiff
```

This also means things like pointers to `alternatives` will be reported badly because they're symlinks.

If you want to cut down on false positives we can use `find`:

```
find /usr/bin -type f -exec dpkg -S {} + > /dev/null
```

On my Debian Jessie machine this results in

```
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/flash-player-properties
```

Comment: Thanks! Just thought it'd check whether there was a more standard way. Note that, when doing this on large file collections, I got an error `zsh: argument list too long: dpkg`, so I ended up doing `find /usr/bin -type f | xargs dpkg -S > /dev/null`

Comment: @a3nm Make that `find /usr/bin -type f -exec dpkg -S {} + >/dev/null`, otherwise this command breaks on file names containing spaces (as does `dkpg -S $(…)`. It happens that Debian doesn't ship any files with names containing spaces in `/usr/bin` (there are some under `/usr/share` at least), but your system might have some.